# import error of inception_utils on "tensorflow models learning"

Tags: python

I am using the inception model in https://github.com/Wnaner/tensorflow_models_nets.git, when I tried to run the file `"inception_v3_train_val.py"`, an error occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inception_v3_train_val.py", line 8, in <module>
    import slim.nets.inception_v3 as inception_v3
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/tensorflow_models_learning/slim/nets/inception_v3.py", line 23, in <module>
    from nets import inception_utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'inception_utils' from 'nets' (/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nets/__init__.py)
```

but when i check the nets folder, it does have a `inception_utils.py`, now i don't know how to solve this problem, hope somebody can help. Thanks very much.